# Copy from one workbook to another with specified dates

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to input the dates, then filter the data based on these two dates. I was able to figure out how select the desired dates but no luck in filtering. Also, is there any chance I can clear all the filters before it filters for the date? This workbook is used by a lot of people and I want to make sure that the date is only thing that is filtered.

The error is: Run-Time error '1004' Autofilter method of Range class failed
My issue is with rngfull .Autofilter line

Here is my code:

```
  Public Sub CreateSubsetWorkbook(StartDate As String, EndDate As String)

        Dim wbkInput As Workbook, wbkOutput As Workbook
        Dim wksInput As Worksheet, wks As Worksheet, wksOutput As Worksheet
        Dim lngLastRow As Long, lngLastCol As Long, lngDateCol As Long
        Dim rngFull As Range, rngResult As Range, rngTarget As Range
        Dim Lastrow As Integer
        lngDateCol = 2
        Set wbkOutput = ThisWorkbook
        Set wbkInput = Workbooks.Open("f:\Sharta\red files\DBr\(NEW SERVER) with Macro.xlsm")
        Set wksInput = wbkInput.Sheets("Sheet1")

            With wksInput
                Set wksOutput = wbkOutput.Sheets("Data Dump")
                Set rngTarget = wksOutput.Cells(1, 1)

                lngLastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                     SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                     SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
                lngLastCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                     SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                     SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
                Set rngFull = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lngLastRow, lngLastCol))

                With rngFull
                    Range.AutoFilter Field:=lngDateCol, _
                                Criteria1:=">=" & StartDate, _
                                Criteria2:="<=" & EndDate

                    Set rngResult = rngFull.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    rngResult.Copy Destination:=rngTarget
                End With

                .AutoFilterMode = False
                If .FilterMode = True Then
                    .ShowAllData
                End If
            End With


        wbkInput.Close Savechanges:=False
        wksOutput.Activate

    End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure if it will change anything, but I think you should specify the `Operator` parameter as well in [`Range.AutoFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter).

Comment: Nope. it says: argument not optional

Comment: Perhaps [edit] your question to show the revised code... right now, we can only guess at what changes you made to get to that error.